# How to set environment variables used by docker container using Bamboo

Tags: docker, bamboo

I am using Bamboo for building and deploying my docker container. My code uses environment variables. I am using a shell script to set values of those variables with those values being hardcoded in .sh file. Ideally, I would like the values for those environment variables to be passed through bamboo variables. One option is to generate a shell script during bamboo build plan and call that shell script from startup file. Is there any better option to set system environment variables using bamboo variables?

Answer (score 1):

When adding the **Docker task** in the **Plan configuration**, you have the option to pass environment variables.

For example, if your Dockerfile has ENV variable test_db_pass you should pass in the Docker task field "**Container environment variables**" the following: `test_db_pass=${bamboo.test_db_pass}`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to define either plan or global variables in Bamboo.
You can then use them in you build.

It's in the documentation :
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/defining-plan-variables-289276859.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for that answer. My question is how to use those bamboo variables to set environment variables. For example, I have a bamboo var:${bamboo.NODE_ENV}. using that I would like to set an environment variable NODE_ENV.